# How to reduce the stored procedures timing using sql server?

Tags: sql, windows

```
CREATE Procedure SearchData ( @Lastname Varchar(250), @Firstname Varchar(25), @City varchar(50),
@Address1 varchar(40),
@HullID varchar(50),
@State varchar(50),
@Status varchar(15),
@Accountpk varchar(40),
@Agentpk varchar(1000),
@Issuecopk varchar(40),
@Productpk varchar(40), @UserType varchar(15), @UserID varchar(30) ) As Begin Set NOCOUNT ON

Declare @Selectionquery         As Varchar(8000)
Declare @USAquery               As Varchar(4000)
Declare @NonUSAquery            As Varchar(4000)
DECLARE @As_User_PK             Varchar(50)
DECLARE @TopRows                Varchar(50)
DECLARE @NONUSQueryColumns      Varchar(1000)
DECLARE @USQueryColumns         Varchar(1000)
DECLARE @QueryColumnsTemp       Varchar(1000)

DECLARE @errordesc varchar(max)

set @Selectionquery         = ''
set @USAquery               = ''
set @NonUSAquery            = ''
Set @NONUSQueryColumns      = ''
Set @USQueryColumns         = ''
Set @QueryColumnsTemp       = ''



Select  @TopRows = Parameter_NUMBER_1 
from    cl_parameters  
where   cl_parameter_code='CLIENTSEARCH' 

select  @As_User_PK = AS_User_PK 
from    as_users 
where   AS_User_ID = @UserID

Set @USQueryColumns = '
    SELECT  PM.POLICY_NO,
            PM.POLICY_STATUS_CODE,
            --MODIFIED BY SARATH FOR COMPATABILITY MODE ON JAN 15 2014
            --ltrim(rtrim(ltrim(rtrim(isnull(CL.first_name,'+''''+' '+''''+') + '+''''+' '+''''+'+ isnull(CL.middle_name,'+''''+''+''''+'))) + '+''''+' '+''''+ '+ CL.last_org_name)) as  last_org_name , 
            Replace(ltrim(rtrim(ltrim(rtrim(isnull(CL.first_name,'+''''+' '+''''+') + '+''''+' '+''''+'+ isnull(CL.middle_name,'+''''+''+''''+'))) + '+''''+' '+''''+ '+ CL.last_org_name)), ''&'', ''-'') as  LASTORGNAME , 
            Replace(CL.FULL_LEGAL_NAME, ''&'', ''-'') as FULL_LEGAL_NAME, 
            CA.ADDRESS_LINE1, 
            CA.TOWN_CITY + '+''''+' '+''''+' +  ISNULL(CLSTATE.STATE_NAME,CA.STATE_CODE), 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), TERM.Term_Start_Date,101)+ '+''''+' - '+''''+' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),TERM.Term_End_Date,101),
            Replace(CLAGENT.LAST_ORG_NAME, ''&'', ''-'') as LAST_ORG_NAME, 
            (Select SCREEN_NAME from CL_CLIENT where CL_CLIENT_PK=PM.ISSUECO_CLIENT_FK), 
            PRODUCT.Screen_Name, 
            PM.PO_POLICY_MASTER_PK'

    Set @USAquery = '
            FROM    dbo.PO_POLICY_MASTER PM 
            INNER JOIN CL_CLIENT CL 
            ON      PM.OWNER_CLIENT_FK = CL.CL_CLIENT_PK'


Set @NONUSQueryColumns = '
    SELECT  PM.POLICY_NO,
            PM.POLICY_STATUS_CODE,
            --MODIFIED BY SARATH FOR COMPATABILITY MODE ON JAN 15 2014
            --ltrim(rtrim(ltrim(rtrim(isnull(CL.first_name,'+''''+' '+''''+') + '+''''+' '+''''+'+ isnull(CL.middle_name,'+''''+''+''''+'))) + '+''''+' '+''''+ '+ CL.last_org_name)) as  last_org_name , 
            Replace(ltrim(rtrim(ltrim(rtrim(isnull(CL.first_name,'+''''+' '+''''+') + '+''''+' '+''''+'+ isnull(CL.middle_name,'+''''+''+''''+'))) + '+''''+' '+''''+ '+ CL.last_org_name)), ''&'', ''-'') as  LASTORGNAME , 
            Replace(CL.FULL_LEGAL_NAME, ''&'', ''-'') as FULL_LEGAL_NAME,
            CA.ADDRESS_LINE1, 
            CA.TOWN_CITY + '+''''+' '+''''+' +  ISNULL(CA.STATE_CODE,'+''''+''+''''+'), 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), TERM.Term_Start_Date,101)+ '+''''+' - '+''''+' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),TERM.Term_End_Date,101),
            Replace(CLAGENT.LAST_ORG_NAME, ''&'', ''-'') as LAST_ORG_NAME, 
            (Select SCREEN_NAME from CL_CLIENT where CL_CLIENT_PK=PM.ISSUECO_CLIENT_FK), 
            PRODUCT.Screen_Name, 
            PM.PO_POLICY_MASTER_PK'
Set @NonUSAquery = '
    FROM    dbo.PO_POLICY_MASTER PM 
    INNER JOIN CL_CLIENT CL 
    ON      PM.OWNER_CLIENT_FK = CL.CL_CLIENT_PK'

IF ISNULL(@Lastname,'') <> ''
    BEGIN
        SET @USAquery   = @USAquery + ' INNER JOIN CL_Client_Name ON CL.CL_CLIENT_PK = CL_CLIENT_NAME.CL_CLIENT_FK'
        SET @USAquery = @USAquery + ' AND UPPER(CL_CLIENT_NAME.LAST_ORG_NAME_UCASE) LIKE UPPER('
        SET @USAquery = @USAquery + ''''+ @Lastname + '%'+ ''''+')'
        SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + ' INNER JOIN CL_Client_Name ON CL.CL_CLIENT_PK = CL_CLIENT_NAME.CL_CLIENT_FK'
        SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + ' AND UPPER(CL_CLIENT_NAME.LAST_ORG_NAME_UCASE) LIKE UPPER('
        SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + ''''+ @Lastname + '%'+ ''''+')'
    END
IF ISNULL(@Firstname,'') <> ''
    BEGIN
        IF ISNULL(@Lastname,'') = ''
            BEGIN
                SET @USAquery   = @USAquery + ' INNER JOIN CL_Client_Name ON CL.CL_CLIENT_PK = CL_CLIENT_NAME.CL_CLIENT_FK '
                SET @USAquery = @USAquery + '  AND UPPER(CL_CLIENT_NAME.FIRST_NAME_UCASE) LIKE UPPER('
                SET @USAquery = @USAquery + ''''+ @Firstname + '%'+ ''''+')'
                SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + ' INNER JOIN CL_Client_Name ON CL.CL_CLIENT_PK = CL_CLIENT_NAME.CL_CLIENT_FK '
                SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + '  AND UPPER(CL_CLIENT_NAME.FIRST_NAME_UCASE) LIKE UPPER('
                SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + ''''+ @Firstname + '%'+ ''''+')'
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @USAquery = @USAquery + ' AND UPPER(CL_CLIENT_NAME.FIRST_NAME_UCASE) LIKE UPPER('
                SET @USAquery = @USAquery + ''''+ @Firstname + '%'+ ''''+')'
                SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + ' AND UPPER(CL_CLIENT_NAME.FIRST_NAME_UCASE) LIKE UPPER('
                SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + ''''+ @Firstname + '%'+ ''''+')'
            END
    END
/* Commented by JB to address the issue that the default adress is billing address hence the policy is not getting diaplayed
SET @USAquery = @USAquery + ' INNER JOIN CL_ADDRESS CA ON CL.CL_CLIENT_PK = CA.CL_CLIENT_FK and CA.Address_Type_Code = ''MAILING'' AND ISNULL(IS_USA,'+''''+'N'+''''+') = '+''''+'Y'+''''+'' */

SET @USAquery = @USAquery + ' INNER JOIN CL_ADDRESS CA ON CL.CL_CLIENT_PK = CA.CL_CLIENT_FK AND ISNULL(IS_USA,'+''''+'N'+''''+') = '+''''+'Y'+''''+''
SET @USAquery = @USAquery + ' INNER JOIN CL_Role_Client crc ON cl.CL_Client_PK = crc.Role_Client_FK AND crc.Source_FK = pm.PO_Policy_Master_PK AND  crc.Role_Type_Code = ''POLICY'' AND crc.Role_Address_FK = ca.CL_Address_PK '
/* Commented by JB to address the issue that the default adress is billing address hence the policy is not getting diaplayed
SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + ' INNER JOIN CL_ADDRESS CA ON CL.CL_CLIENT_PK = CA.CL_CLIENT_FK and CA.Address_Type_Code = ''MAILING'' AND ISNULL(IS_USA,'+''''+'N'+''''+') = '+''''+'N'+''''+'' */ SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + ' INNER JOIN CL_ADDRESS CA ON CL.CL_CLIENT_PK = CA.CL_CLIENT_FK AND ISNULL(IS_USA,'+''''+'N'+''''+') = '+''''+'N'+''''+''
SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + ' INNER JOIN CL_Role_Client crc ON cl.CL_Client_PK = crc.Role_Client_FK AND crc.Source_FK = pm.PO_Policy_Master_PK AND crc.Role_Type_Code = ''POLICY'' AND crc.Role_Address_FK = ca.CL_Address_PK '

IF ISNULL(@City,'') <> ''
    BEGIN
        SET @USAquery = @USAquery + '  AND UPPER(CA.TOWN_CITY) LIKE UPPER('
        SET @USAquery = @USAquery + ''''+ @City + '%'+ ''''+')'
        SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + '  AND UPPER(CA.TOWN_CITY) LIKE UPPER('
        SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + ''''+ @City + '%'+ ''''+')'
    END
SET @USAquery = @USAquery + ' INNER JOIN PO_RISK_MASTER RISK ON RISK.PO_POLICY_MASTER_FK = PM.PO_POLICY_MASTER_PK'

SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + ' INNER JOIN PO_RISK_MASTER RISK ON RISK.PO_POLICY_MASTER_FK = PM.PO_POLICY_MASTER_PK'

IF ISNULL(@Address1,'') <> ''
    BEGIN
        SET @USAquery = @USAquery + '  AND UPPER(CA.ADDRESS_LINE1) LIKE UPPER('
        SET @USAquery = @USAquery + ''''+ '%' + @Address1 + '%'+ ''''+')'
        SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + '  AND UPPER(CA.ADDRESS_LINE1) LIKE UPPER('
        SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + ''''+ '%' + @Address1 + '%'+ ''''+')'
    END
IF ISNULL(@HullID,'') <> ''
    BEGIN
        SET @USAquery = @USAquery + '  AND UPPER(RISK.RISK_EXTERNAL_ID) LIKE UPPER('
        SET @USAquery = @USAquery + ''''+ '%' + @HullID + '%'+ ''''+')'
        SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + '  AND UPPER(RISK.RISK_EXTERNAL_ID) LIKE UPPER('
        SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + ''''+ '%' + @HullID + '%'+ ''''+')'
    END
SET @USAquery = @USAquery + ' INNER JOIN CL_COUNTRY_STATE CLSTATE ON CA.Country_Code = CLSTATE.CL_Country_Code AND CLSTATE.STATE_CODE = CA.STATE_CODE'
IF ISNULL(@State,'') <> ''
    BEGIN
        SET @USAquery = @USAquery + ' AND UPPER(CLSTATE.STATE_NAME) LIKE UPPER('
        SET @USAquery = @USAquery + ''''+ @State + '%'+ ''''+')'
        SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + ' AND UPPER(CA.STATE_CODE) LIKE UPPER('
        SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + ''''+ @State + '%'+ ''''+')'
    END
SET @USAquery = @USAquery + ' 
INNER JOIN PO_TERM_MASTER TERM 
ON      TERM.PO_POLICY_MASTER_FK = PM.PO_POLICY_MASTER_PK 
AND     TERM.PO_TERM_MASTER_PK = (SELECT    max(po_term_master_pk) 
                                    FROM    PO_TERM_MASTER 
                                    WHERE   PO_TERM_MASTER.PO_POLICY_MASTER_FK = PM.po_policy_master_PK) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PA_ACCOUNT_MASTER ACCT 
ON      ACCT.pa_account_master_pk = PM.PO_AGENT_ACCOUNT_FK 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CL_CLIENT CLAGENT   
ON      CLAGENT.cl_client_pk = ACCT.owner_client_fk 
INNER JOIN PR_PRODUCT PRODUCT 
ON      PRODUCT.PR_PRODUCT_PK = PM.PR_PRODUCT_FK 
WHERE   1=1 and PRODUCT.PR_Product_Code <> ''BBRENTAL'' '

SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + ' 
INNER JOIN PO_TERM_MASTER TERM 
ON      TERM.PO_POLICY_MASTER_FK = PM.PO_POLICY_MASTER_PK 
AND     TERM.PO_TERM_MASTER_PK = (SELECT    max(po_term_master_pk) 
                                    FROM    PO_TERM_MASTER 
                                    WHERE   PO_TERM_MASTER.PO_POLICY_MASTER_FK = PM.po_policy_master_PK) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PA_ACCOUNT_MASTER ACCT 
ON      ACCT.pa_account_master_pk = PM.PO_AGENT_ACCOUNT_FK 
LEFT OUTER JOIN CL_CLIENT CLAGENT   
ON      CLAGENT.cl_client_pk = ACCT.owner_client_fk 
INNER JOIN PR_PRODUCT PRODUCT 
ON      PRODUCT.PR_PRODUCT_PK = PM.PR_PRODUCT_FK 
WHERE   1=1 and PRODUCT.PR_Product_Code <> ''BBRENTAL'' '

IF ISNULL(@Status,'') <> ''
    BEGIN
        IF ISNULL(@Status,'') <> 'ALL'
            BEGIN
                IF      ISNULL(@Status,'') = 'Quote'
                    BEGIN
                        SET @USAquery = @USAquery + 
                        ' AND   exists(
                                select  0
                                from    dbo.po_transaction pot
                                where   pot.po_policy_master_fk = pm.po_policy_master_pk
                                and     pot.pr_tran_type_code = ''NEWBUSINESS''
                                and     pot.transaction_cycle_code not in (''BOUND'',''VOIDED'',''ISSUED'',''BINDEREXPIRED''))'

                        SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + 
                        ' AND   exists(
                                select  0
                                from    dbo.po_transaction pot
                                where   pot.po_policy_master_fk = pm.po_policy_master_pk
                                and     pot.pr_tran_type_code = ''NEWBUSINESS''
                                and     pot.transaction_cycle_code not in (''BOUND'',''VOIDED'',''ISSUED'',''BINDEREXPIRED''))'

                    END
                ELSE IF ISNULL(@Status,'') = 'Bound'
                    BEGIN
                        SET @USAquery = @USAquery + 
                        ' AND   exists(
                                select  0
                                from    dbo.po_transaction pot
                                where   pot.po_policy_master_fk = pm.po_policy_master_pk
                                and     pot.pr_tran_type_code = ''NEWBUSINESS''
                                and     pot.transaction_cycle_code in (''BOUND'',''BINDEREXPIRED''))'

                        SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + 
                        ' AND   exists(
                                select  0
                                from    dbo.po_transaction pot
                                where   pot.po_policy_master_fk = pm.po_policy_master_pk
                                and     pot.pr_tran_type_code = ''NEWBUSINESS''
                                and     pot.transaction_cycle_code in (''BOUND'',''BINDEREXPIRED''))'
                    END                     
                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        SET @USAquery = @USAquery + '  AND PM.policy_status_code='
                        SET @USAquery = @USAquery + ''''+ @Status + ''''+''
                        SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + '  AND PM.policy_status_code='
                        SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + ''''+ @Status + ''''+''
                    END
            END
    END
IF ISNULL(@Accountpk,'') <> ''
    BEGIN
    IF ISNULL(@Accountpk,'') <> 'ALL'
        BEGIN
            SET @USAquery = @USAquery + ' AND PM.Po_Agent_Account_Fk in ('
            SET @USAquery = @USAquery + ''''+ @Agentpk + ''''+')'
            SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + ' AND PM.Po_Agent_Account_Fk in ('
            SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + ''''+ @Agentpk + ''''+')'
        END
    END
IF ISNULL(@Issuecopk,'') <> ''
    BEGIN
        IF ISNULL(@Issuecopk,'') <> 'ALL'
            BEGIN
                SET @USAquery = @USAquery + ' AND PM.ISSUECO_CLIENT_FK='
                SET @USAquery = @USAquery + ''''+ @Issuecopk + ''''+''
                SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + ' AND PM.ISSUECO_CLIENT_FK='
                SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + ''''+ @Issuecopk + ''''+''
            END
    END
IF ISNULL(@Productpk,'') <> ''
    BEGIN
        IF ISNULL(@Productpk,'') <> 'ALL'
            BEGIN
                SET @USAquery = @USAquery + ' AND PM.pr_product_fk='
                SET @USAquery = @USAquery + ''''+ @Productpk + ''''+''
                SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + ' AND PM.pr_product_fk='
                SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + ''''+ @Productpk + ''''+''
            END
    END
IF ISNULL(@UserType,'') = 'AGENT'
    BEGIN
        SET @USAquery = @USAquery + '                       
            AND PM.PO_AGENT_ACCOUNT_FK IN(SELECT PA_ACCOUNT_MASTER_PK FROM PA_ACCOUNT_MASTER 
            WHERE   OWNER_CLIENT_FK IN (SELECT AGENT_CLIENT_FK FROM AS_USER_AGENT 
            WHERE AS_USER_FK = '+''''+convert(varchar,@As_User_PK) + ''''+''+ ' ))'

        SET @NonUSAquery = @NonUSAquery + '
            AND PM.PO_AGENT_ACCOUNT_FK IN(SELECT PA_ACCOUNT_MASTER_PK FROM PA_ACCOUNT_MASTER 
            WHERE   OWNER_CLIENT_FK IN (SELECT AGENT_CLIENT_FK FROM AS_USER_AGENT 
            WHERE AS_USER_FK = '+''''+convert(varchar,@As_User_PK) + ''''+''+ ' ))'

    END
-- Create table #tblcount (Nofofrows numeric(18,0))

-- SET @Selectionquery = 'Insert into #tblcount select count(PM.PO_POLICY_MASTER_PK) ' + @USAquery + ' UNION ALL ' + 'select count(PM.PO_POLICY_MASTER_PK) ' + @NonUSAquery

-- Exec(@Selectionquery) -- Set @errordesc = ''

-- select @errordesc = Error_Description from screen_error_message where Error_No=5339

-- If (select sum(Nofofrows) from #tblcount) > @TopRows -- Begin -- --Set @Selectionquery = 'Select ''NOTE'', '''', ''Too Many Rows Returned'', '''', '''', '''', '''', '''', '''', ''0''' -- Set @Selectionquery = 'Select ''NOTE'', ''>' + convert(varchar(3), @TopRows) + ' rows'', ''' + @errordesc +''', '''', '''', '''', '''', '''', '''', ''0''' -- Exec(@Selectionquery) -- End -- else -- Begin

        Create table #tblpolicydata (
                POLICY_NO varchar(25),
                POLICY_STATUS_CODE varchar(25),
                LAST_ORG_NAME varchar(250), 
                FULL_LEGAL_NAME varchar(250),
                 ADDRESS_LINE1 varchar(250),
                TOWN_CITY varchar(250),
                TERM_DATES varchar(25),
                 AGENTLAST_ORG_NAME varchar(250),
                ISSUECO varchar(250),
                PRODUCT varchar(50),
                PO_POLICY_MASTER_PK numeric(18,0))
        --MODIFIED BY SARATH FOR COMPATABILITY MODE ON JAN 15 2014
/* SET @Selectionquery = 'Insert into #tblpolicydata ' + @USQueryColumns + ' ' + @USAquery +
' UNION ALL ' + @NONUSQueryColumns + ' ' + @NonUSAquery + ' ORDER BY CL.LAST_ORG_NAME' */ SET @Selectionquery = 'Insert into #tblpolicydata ' + @USQueryColumns + ' ' + @USAquery +
' UNION ALL ' + @NONUSQueryColumns + ' ' + @NonUSAquery + ''

        Exec(@Selectionquery)

        update  #tblpolicydata 
        Set     POLICY_STATUS_CODE = (Select pot.transaction_cycle_code 
                                    From    dbo.po_transaction pot
                                    where   pot.po_policy_master_fk = #tblpolicydata.PO_POLICY_MASTER_PK
                                    and     pot.pr_tran_type_code = 'NEWBUSINESS')
        where   POLICY_STATUS_CODE = 'Prospect'


        Select  POLICY_NO,
                upper(POLICY_STATUS_CODE) POLICY_STATUS_CODE,
                LAST_ORG_NAME,
                FULL_LEGAL_NAME,
                ADDRESS_LINE1,
                TOWN_CITY,
                TERM_DATES,
                AGENTLAST_ORG_NAME,
                ISSUECO,
                PRODUCT,
                PO_POLICY_MASTER_PK
        From    #tblpolicydata 
        GROUP BY POLICY_NO,
                upper(POLICY_STATUS_CODE),
                LAST_ORG_NAME,
                FULL_LEGAL_NAME,
                ADDRESS_LINE1,
                TOWN_CITY,
                TERM_DATES,
                AGENTLAST_ORG_NAME,
                ISSUECO,
                PRODUCT,
                PO_POLICY_MASTER_PK
        order   by POLICY_NO

        Drop table #tblpolicydata
-- End -- Drop table #tblcount --Exec INSCS_ClientSearch '','','','','','','India','','','','','','' Set NOCOUNT OFF End
```

It execute more time. How to reduce the time ?

Comment: look at the execution plan and see what its doing rather than just posting mass amount of SQL here and hoping someone else does it for you

Comment: @CSK break the `Stored Procedure` into smaller chunks of statements and run the query with the `Actual Execution Plan` on. Try to add a proper `index` on the most used columns and check if there are any `Table scan` that's taking place.

Comment: here it take execute more time.i want to reduce the time to execute.please

Comment: please give some ideas to reduce the time

Comment: You didn't even post the code, how could we give you any assistance? Stack Overflow users are not clairvoyant.

Comment: @Jacob I messed up that edit, now see if you can make something of those 300 lines.

Comment: Well just from first glance, you should be able to use sp_executesql instead of exec to get improved performance. Read this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/17/exec-vs-sp_executesql/ You could make some of these subqueries modular (maybe use functions) rather than building one giant concatenation of multiple queries. Have you looked at the execution plan?

Comment: You can get rid of all those dynamic inner joins and replace with a non-dynamic LEFT OUTER JOIN and then check for NULL before applying your where clause. Also if you are no using the default collation you don't need UCASE()

Answer (score 0):

While waiting on an email I was able to translate this away from that dynamic query stuff. Whenever you see a filter like this using fields passed in, 9/10 it is always going to be more performant to LEFT OUTER JOIN your filter tables and use something like:

```
WHERE
  (@FilterField1 IS NULL OR(MyTable.Field1 = @FilterField1))
```

You really don't need that temp processing as you are grabbing the fields needed in the main query. Just reassign the value to POLICY_STATUS_CODE in the main query.

Again, the subquery to get MAX(po_term_master_pk) is not needed, You have the data in the detail and are already grouping the results you return, why the subquery in the INNER JOIN?

Your status check is going to slow the query down a lot. You are already hitting all the fields in the main query, then you are grouping by all but the status flags. Simply use calculated fields and them sum them in an outer query.

The code posted below will not compile nor will it likely give you correct data, however, you may wish to use it to start improving the performance of what you have posted above.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        BoundFlag  = CASE WHEN MAX(BoundFlag) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        VoidedFlag = CASE WHEN MAX(VoidedFlag) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        IssuedFlag = CASE WHEN MAX(IssuedFlag) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        BinderExpiredFlag= CASE WHEN MAX(BinderExpiredFlag) =1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        MaxPoTermMasterPK= max(po_term_master_pk)   
    FROM
    (

        SELECT  

                BoundFlag  = CASE WHEN pot.transaction_cycle_code ='BOUND' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
                VoidedFlag = CASE WHEN pot.transaction_cycle_code ='VOIDED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
                IssuedFlag = CASE WHEN pot.transaction_cycle_code ='ISSUED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
                BinderExpiredFlag= CASE WHEN pot.transaction_cycle_code ='BINDEREXPIRED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
                HasProspectFlag = CASE WHEN POLICY_STATUS_CODE = 'Prospect' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
                POLICY_STATUS_CODE = CASE WHEN POLICY_STATUS_CODE = 'NEWBUSINESS'  THEN  'PROSPECT' ELSE POLICY_STATUS_CODE,
                PM.POLICY_NO,
                --MODIFIED BY SARATH FOR COMPATABILITY MODE ON JAN 15 2014
                --ltrim(rtrim(ltrim(rtrim(isnull(CL.first_name,'+''''+' '+''''+') + '+''''+' '+''''+'+ isnull(CL.middle_name,'+''''+''+''''+'))) + '+''''+' '+''''+ '+ CL.last_org_name)) as  last_org_name , 
                Replace(ltrim(rtrim(ltrim(rtrim(isnull(CL.first_name,'+''''+' '+''''+') + '+''''+' '+''''+'+ isnull(CL.middle_name,'+''''+''+''''+'))) + '+''''+' '+''''+ '+ CL.last_org_name)), ''&'', ''-'') as  LASTORGNAME , 
                Replace(CL.FULL_LEGAL_NAME, ''&'', ''-'') as FULL_LEGAL_NAME, 
                CA.ADDRESS_LINE1, 
                CA.TOWN_CITY + '+''''+' '+''''+' +  ISNULL(CLSTATE.STATE_NAME,CA.STATE_CODE), 
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), TERM.Term_Start_Date,101)+ '+''''+' - '+''''+' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),TERM.Term_End_Date,101),
                Replace(CLAGENT.LAST_ORG_NAME, ''&'', ''-'') as LAST_ORG_NAME, 
                (Select SCREEN_NAME from CL_CLIENT where CL_CLIENT_PK=PM.ISSUECO_CLIENT_FK), 
                PRODUCT.Screen_Name, 
                PM.PO_POLICY_MASTER_PK
                FROM
                dbo.PO_POLICY_MASTER PM 
                INNER JOIN  dbo.PO_POLICY_MASTER PM ON PM.<PrimaryKey>=FlagDetail.<PrimaryKey>
                INNER JOIN CL_CLIENT CL ON      PM.OWNER_CLIENT_FK = CL.CL_CLIENT_PK
                LEFT OUTER  JOIN CL_Client_Name ON CL.CL_CLIENT_PK = CL_CLIENT_NAME.CL_CLIENT_FK
                LEFT OUTER JOIN CL_ADDRESS CA ON CL.CL_CLIENT_PK = CA.CL_CLIENT_FK IS_USA='Y' --YOU DNOT NEED IS NULL ISNULL(IS_USA,'+''''+'N'+''''+') = '+''''+'Y'+'''
                LEFT OUTER JOIN CL_Role_Client crc_us ON cl.CL_Client_PK = crc.Role_Client_FK AND crc.Source_FK = pm.PO_Policy_Master_PK AND  crc.Role_Type_Code = 'POLICY' AND crc.Role_Address_FK = ca.CL_Address_PK
                --YOU DONT NEED TO JOIN AGAIN FOR NON US - YOU ARE USING THE SAME CONDITION LEFT OUTER JOIN CL_Role_Client crc_us ON cl.CL_Client_PK = crc.Role_Client_FK AND crc.Source_FK = pm.PO_Policy_Master_PK AND  crc.Role_Type_Code = 'POLICY' AND crc.Role_Address_FK = ca.CL_Address_PK
                INNER JOIN PO_RISK_MASTER RISK ON RISK.PO_POLICY_MASTER_FK = PM.PO_POLICY_MASTER_PK
                LEFT OUTER JOIN CL_COUNTRY_STATE CLSTATE ON CA.Country_Code = CLSTATE.CL_Country_Code AND CLSTATE.STATE_CODE = CA.STATE_CODE
                /* SEE COMMENTS - TRY TO AVOID A SUBQUERY IN YOUR JOINS ! 
                INNER JOIN PO_TERM_MASTER TERM ON TERM.PO_POLICY_MASTER_FK = PM.PO_POLICY_MASTER_PK 
                        --You could replace this subquery below with a master subquery reducing burden on the join
                        AND     TERM.PO_TERM_MASTER_PK = 
                        (
                            SELECT    max(po_term_master_pk) 
                            FROM    PO_TERM_MASTER 
                            WHERE   PO_TERM_MASTER.PO_POLICY_MASTER_FK = PM.po_policy_master_PK
                        ) 
                */
                LEFT OUTER JOIN PA_ACCOUNT_MASTER ACCT ON ACCT.pa_account_master_pk = PM.PO_AGENT_ACCOUNT_FK 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN CL_CLIENT CLAGENT ON CLAGENT.cl_client_pk = ACCT.owner_client_fk 
                INNER JOIN PR_PRODUCT PRODUCT ON PRODUCT.PR_PRODUCT_PK = PM.PR_PRODUCT_FK 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN  dbo.po_transaction pot ON pot.po_policy_master_fk = pm.po_policy_master_pk and pot.pr_tran_type_code = 'NEWBUSINESS'
            WHERE   
                (@LastName IS NULL OR (CL_CLIENT_NAME.LAST_ORG_NAME_UCASE LIKE  @Lastname + '%')) --Check your collation - I bet you dont need UCASE
                AND
                (@FisrtName IS NULL OR (CL_CLIENT_NAME.FIRST_ORG_NAME_UCASE LIKE  @Fisrtname + '%'))--Check your collation - I bet you dont need UCASE
                AND
                (@City IS NULL OR (CA.TOWN_CITY LIKE  @City + '%') -- You probally dont need UPPERCASE HERE Check your collation
                AND
                (@Address1 IS NULL OR(CA.ADDRESS_LINE1 LIKE '%' +@Address1 + '%'))
                AND
                (@HullID IS NULL OR(RISK.RISK_EXTERNAL_ID LIKE '%' + @HullID + '%'))
                AND
                (@StateID IS NULL OR(CLSTATE.STATE_NAME LIKE @State + '%'))
                AND
                (1=1 and PRODUCT.PR_Product_Code <> 'BBRENTAL') --WHats with the 1=1?
                AND
                (@UserType<>'AGENT' OR(PM.PO_AGENT_ACCOUNT_FK IN(SELECT PA_ACCOUNT_MASTER_PK FROM PA_ACCOUNT_MASTER WHERE   OWNER_CLIENT_FK IN (SELECT AGENT_CLIENT_FK FROM AS_USER_AGENT WHERE AS_USER_FK = convert(varchar,@As_User_PK) )))
                AND
                ((@Accountpk IS NULL OR @Accountpk='ALL') OR(PM.Po_Agent_Account_Fk =@Agentpk))
                AND
                ((@Issuecopk IS NULL OR @Issuecopk='ALL') OR(PM.ISSUECO_CLIENT_FK =@Issuecopk))
                AND
                ((@Productpk IS NULL OR @Productpk='ALL') OR(PM.pr_product_fk =@Issuecopk))

    )AS DETAIL
    GROUP BY
        PM.POLICY_NO,
        PM.POLICY_STATUS_CODE,
        LASTORGNAME , 
        FULL_LEGAL_NAME, 
        CA.ADDRESS_LINE1, 
        CA.TOWN_CITY,
        CLSTATE.STATE_NAME,
        CA.STATE_CODE, 
        TERM.Term_Start_Date,
        TERM.Term_End_Date
        CLAGENT.LAST_ORG_NAME,
        LAST_ORG_NAME, 
        PM.ISSUECO_CLIENT_FK, 
        PRODUCT.Screen_Name, 
        PM.PO_POLICY_MASTER_PK,
        pr_tran_type_code 
)AS SUMMARY
WHERE
    (PO_TERM_MASTER_PK = MaxPoTermMasterPK)
    AND
    (
        (@Status IS NULL )
        OR
        (
            (@Status ='Quote' AND  (IsBound + IsVoided + IsIssued + IsBinderExipired = 0))
            OR
            (@Status ='Bound' AND ( IsBound + IsBinderExipired > 0))
        )
    )
ORDER BY
    POLICY_NO
```